# Integral of function for $ f : [−1, 1] → \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, functions

$$ f : [−1, 1] → \mathbb{R}$$

[image]

What is the value of $$ \int_{-1}^{1} f (x^2 -1) dx$$

**My approach**

If i look at the function then it is forming $f(x) = -\left| {x} \right|+1$ in the domain of $[-1,1]$

If i analyze the function then i get $f(x) = x+1$ for $x\in[-1,0]$
and  $f(x) = -x+1$ for $x\in[0,1]$.

If i continue solving this i get $2$ *i.e.* $(2+ \frac{1}{3} -\frac{1}{3})$ but the answer is $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: We can't know where you went wrong if you omit your calculations! :)

Comment: Just from a quick common-sense check, $f(x^2-1)\le1$ when $-1\le x \le1$, so the correct answer must be less than 2. Just confirming that your answer has to be wrong.

Comment: @Peter I’ve checked the answer and it is 2/3. Also i checked my calculations and my answer is coming out to be 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every $x \in [-1,1]$, one has $-1\leq x^2-1 \leq 0$. Since $f(u)=u+1$ for every $ u \in[-1,0]$, you get that
$$\int_{-1}^{1} f (x^2 -1) dx = \int_{-1}^{1} (x^2-1)+1 dx = \int_{-1}^{1} x^2 dx = \frac{2}{3}.$$

Comment: Understood. I have to check the behavior of the function when $x= x^2 -1$ not just the behavior of $x$ in the given domain